# Using Django session outside of view

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

My Django application does not have user logins. Anyone can access the application and vote on different lists of songs. What I want is that when a user votes, the user should not be allowed to vote again in that list.

Here is my AJAX code

**ajax.py**

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

s = SessionStore()

@dajaxice_register
def update_disable(request):
    #updates song votes and disables all vote buttons on page
    s['can_vote'] = False
    s.save()
    return dajax.json()
```

I need to get the session_key I think to make this work. How do I get that? The documentation isn't exactly clear on this.

This is what I'm doing in the HTML

```
{% if perms.hunt.can_vote %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom vote" onclick="update();">Vote as Favourite</button>
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom vote" disabled="disabled">Vote as Favourite</button>
{% endif %}
```

Am I approaching the Djnago Session concept correctly? Any advice on this is appreciated.

Comment: i think you shouldn't use the session for that, since users could just clear out their session. use the ip address for that and save it in a datastore/cache. if it is already in he can't vote.
Also you can't be sure that a user could vote twice. since some people get a new IP address if they reconnect to their internet provider. so its not that easy.

Comment: This is not outside a view. It's inside a view. You have access to the request object, therefore you have access to the session. The docs do explain exactly how to access the session from the request.

Answer (score 0):

From Django Documentation: [How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions)

**Django provides full support for anonymous sessions. The session framework lets you store  and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies.**

There you can find:

1. Using cached sessions
2. Using file-based sessions
3. Using cookie-based sessions

You can use cookies for store which list an user has voted.